# speed up SELECT DISTINCT using keys

Tags: mysql, optimization, select

If I use the SELECT DISTINCT query on a table with 100 rows where 98 entries of the table are identical and the other 2 are identical, would it still go through all 100 rows just to return the 2 distinct results?

Is there a way to use indexing/keys etc so that instead of going through all 100 rows, it would instead go through 2 rows?

**####EDIT#####**

so I added this index:

```
KEY `column` (`column`(1)),
```

but then when I do

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT column FROM tablename
```

it's still saying that it's going through all rows rather than just distinct ones

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use constraints to avoid all the duplicate inserts

Comment: Why the `(1)` length when you created the index? If you want the query resolved using only the index then the index needs to be on the entire column, not just the first byte/character.

Comment: I changed it to 20 (none of the entries in the column is longer than that) and it still goes through all entries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating an index on the column or set of columns being queried with `DISTINCT` will speed up the query. Rather than looking through every row it will use the two entries in the index. With only 100 rows though, the difference may not even be detectable.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on almost similar thing. I am trying to get the distinct values from a table with 400Mill rows.

I even have the key on that attribute. It is still doing the full scan. the only difference is is that it is full index scan rather than a disc scan.

i have only 10 distinct values but i didnt resulted even after 5minutes and i killed it.